# RSA - Twin Primes across two messages

Tags: rsa, attack, prime-numbers

This was a CTF challenge I was unable to solve, but I thought I may had come close.

We were given two $N$'s $N_1$ and $N_2$ each calculated with $P_1 \times Q_1$ and $P_2 \times Q_2$; however, $P_1 = P_2 + 2$ where $P_2$ was still prime.
$Q_1, P_2, Q_2$ where calculated by what I think was a fairly standard method (using sage)

```
bitlen = 1024
t = 32
upper_bound = bitlen+t
lower_bound = bitlen-t
q1 = random_prime(2^(lower_bound), lbound=2^(lower_bound-1)+2^(lower_bound-2), proof=False)
```

I attempted to attack this algebraically, using $$Q_1N_2 + 2Q_1Q_2 - Q_2N_1 = 0$$
Then
$$
Q_2 = \frac{N_2}{P_2}
$$
$$
Q_1 = \frac{N_1}{P_1}
$$
$$
    = \frac{N_1}{(P_2 + 2)}
$$
$$
    = \frac{N_1}{((N_2 / Q_2) + 2)}
$$
$$
    Q_1 = \frac{(N_1Q_2)}{(N_2 + 2Q_2)}
$$
And substituting that back into the first equation to have a function with only factors of $Q_2$; however, I was left with really ugly quadratics that didn't seem to have solutions $\neq 0$. So I assume my math/logic was wrong somewhere along the line and there isn't an algebraic solution.

EDIT: I just noticed that when it checked for primality of the twin prime it uses the `is_pseudoprime()` function and not the `is_prime()` function.

Would anyone be able to suggest how to attack this

(This CTF is no longer running, and I have been told a solution will be released very shortly but I was hoping for something more descriptive, please)

Comment: Sorry about the type, it is fixed now.
$P_2,Q_1, Q_2$ were all generated using sage's `random_prime()` function as shown above for $Q_1$

$e = 65537$ 
There was no other information available.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that the check uses `is_pseudoprime()` to check for twin primes. I imagine this is where another weakness may be. I'll add this to my initial question

Comment: The method shown to generate $Q_1 $ is suitable for $Q_2$, but not for $P_2$ contrary to a statement in the question. $P_1$ and $P_2$ are twin primes, they must be co-generated. Is there some intel about how $P_1$ and $P_2$ are generated, or a currently unstated characteristic they may have? Also: the title includes "two messages", suggesting there was more givens, and that the goal was not to factor $N_1$ or/and $N_2$.

Comment: The original file contains $N_1$, and a cipher $C_1$. It also contains $N_2$ and a cipher $C_2$. There is one exponent of $65537$. $P_1$ and $P_2$ is generated by continuously creating a new prime number ($P_2$) and checking if $P_2 + 2$ is a `psuedoprime`. If it is then it assigns $P_2 +2$ to $P_1$ and breaks out of the loop.

Comment: In practice, `is_pseudoprime()` does not let a composite slip when fed randomly seeded values, which would be the case here (there is no documented example of `is_pseudoprime()` failing in such case). Is there some indication about the same message being encrypted into $C_1$ and $C_2$, using textbook RSA $M\mapsto C_i=M^e\bmod N_i$ ? About $e$ used? If the question is: how to factor RSA moduli $N_1$ and $N_2$ about the same size knowing that a prime $P_2$ about (and above) half the size of $N_2$ divides $N_2$, and $P_1=P_2+1$ divides $N_1$: I do not see a method for that.

Comment: Because this is a CTF I will not give the solution just yet,  
but instead a hint: continued fraction

Answer (score -1):

Because this is a CTF I will not give the solution,
but will give a hint as an answer.

Continued fraction.
Use a variation of Lehman's.